# Restore an LDIF backup of an LDAP server to a new install of OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've tried to restore an ldif backup of an LDAP server to a fresh Centos 7 machine on which I've installed OpenLDAP to. I've been using these instructions https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1

up to the point, but not including, the chdomain file.

The command I used to upload the file was 
slapadd -c -l  ldapBackup.ldif

But the response I got was

```
The first database does not allow slapadd; using the first available one(2)

hdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": database already in use.
backend_startup_one (type=hdb, suffix="dc=my-domain,dc=com"): bi_db_open failed!(-1)

slap_startup_failed
```

Comment: The error message suggests your domain is already in use, did you only try uploading a single time? Seems like you already tried adding it once. Are there any file in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase=*`? If so do they mention your domain? If so you can remove those files and try importing again.

Comment: Only got olcDatabase ={0}config.ldif  olcDatabase ={1}monitor.ldif olcDatabase ={-1}frontend.ldif olcDatabase ={2}hdb.ldif

Comment: if you look in `olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif` does that mention your domain? It likely does. It could be leftover from a partial import.